# Precasted About Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I do need a good About Dialog for my app, something like the Visual Studio About Dialog. I'm kinda too lazy to design it myself and make all the properties.

Does anybody know if there's a precasted one somewhere? Google didn't help me at all...

C# + Winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but [this](http://dotnetperls.com/customized-dialog-windows) is a good start. All you would need to do is alter the constructor to display exactly what you want.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Visual Studio,  right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and choose "Add New Item".  One of the items you can add is an About Box... with properties of your program already included.

I'm not sure if this is true in the Express editions, but it's there in the full-blown versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I use the express edition of VS 2013 and the "About Box" is available just as it is with the full version.